# Unable to identify where to specify header/footer in an R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

### Problem

I have one module in my shiny app that resides in the `R` directory. Without modularizing, the `app.R` does not throw any errors. But with the module I get this error:

```
Error: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav_panel()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
```

### Code

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

# Names
name_inputs <- layout_columns(

  textInput(
    inputId = "iname",
    label = "Name of Instructor:",
    value = ""
  ),

  textInput(
    inputId = "pname1",
    label = "Name1:",
    value = ""
  ),

  textInput(
    inputId = "pname2",
    label = "Name2:",
    value = ""
  ),

  col_widths = c(4, 4, 4)
)



# UI

ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$head(

    tags$style(HTML("
      .btn-group-label {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .label-spacing {
        margin-right: 10px;
        min-width: 150px;
        display: inline-block;
      }"))
  ),

  name_inputs,
  mod_part_A_ui("part_A")

)


# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mod_part_A_server("part_A")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Module

```
mod_part_A_ui <- function(id) {
 ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("add"), "New"),
    br(),
    br(),
    tabsetPanel(ns("tabs"))
  )
}

mod_part_A_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      ns <- session$ns

      observeEvent(input$add, {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            textInput(
              inputId = ns("e_name"),
              label = "E name:",
              value = ""
            ),
            actionButton(ns("submit_e_name"), "Submit"),
            title = "Enter e name",
            footer = NULL,
            size = "s",
            easyClose = FALSE
          )
        )

      })

      observeEvent(input$submit_e_name, {
        removeModal()

        e_name <- input$e_name

        insertTab(inputId = "tabs",
                  tabPanel(
                    title = e_name,
                    tagList(
                      br(),
                      layout_columns(
                        tagList(
                          lapply(
                            c("F", "H", "T",
                              "R", "E", "A", "C",
                              "A", "C"),
                            function(x) {
                              div(
                                class = "btn-group-label",
                                span(class = "label-spacing", paste0(x, ":")),
                                radioGroupButtons(
                                  inputId = ns(paste0("A_", gsub("\\s", "", x))),
                                  choiceNames = c("+", "-", "x"),
                                  choiceValues = c("p and p",
                                                   "p and n",
                                                   "not p"),
                                  status = "primary",
                                  size = "normal",
                                  selected = character(0)
                                )
                              )
                            }
                          )
                        ),

                        textAreaInput(inputId = ns("A_comments"),
                                      label = "Notes:",
                                      placeholder = "Add your notes here.",
                                      width = "600px", height = "500px"),

                        col_widths = c(4, 8)
                      ),
                      actionButton(ns("save"), "Save")
                    )

                  )
        )
      })

    }
  )
}
```

### Traceback

The error traceback:

```
30.
stop(msg, call. = FALSE)
29.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
28.
lapply(seq_len(length(tabs)), buildTabItem, tabsetId = tabsetId,
foundSelected = foundSelected, tabs = tabs, textFilter = textFilter)
27.
buildTabset(..., ulClass = paste0("nav nav-", type), id = id,
selected = selected)
26.
tabsetPanel_(..., type = "tabs", id = id, selected = selected,
header = header, footer = footer)
25.
new(...)
24.
func(..., id = id, selected = selected, header = header, footer = footer)
23.
remove_first_class(func(..., id = id, selected = selected, header = header,
footer = footer))
22.
tabsetPanel(ns("tabs"))
21.
dots_list(...)
20.
tagList(actionButton(ns("add"), "New"), br(), br(), tabsetPanel(ns("tabs"))) at mod_part_A.R#3
19.
mod_part_A_ui("part_A")
18.
dots_list(...)
17.
div(class = "container-fluid", ...)
16.
list2(...)
15.
bootstrapPage(div(class = "container-fluid", ...), title = title,
theme = theme, lang = lang)
14.
shiny::fluidPage(..., title = title, theme = theme, lang = lang,
if (isTRUE(theme_version(theme) >= 5)) component_dependencies())
13.
as_page(shiny::fluidPage(..., title = title, theme = theme, lang = lang,
if (isTRUE(theme_version(theme) >= 5)) component_dependencies()),
theme = theme)
12.
page_fluid(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("\n .btn-group-label {\n display: flex;\n align-items: center;\n flex-wrap: wrap;\n }\n .label-spacing {\n margin-right: 10px;\n min-width: 150px;\n display: inline-block;\n }"))),
name_inputs, mod_part_A_ui("part_A"))
11.
..stacktraceon..({
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib) ...
10.
eval(exprs, envir)
9.
eval(exprs, envir)
8.
sourceUTF8(fullpath, envir = new.env(parent = sharedEnv))
7.
func(fname, ...)
6.
appObj()
5.
shinyAppDir_appR("app.R", appDir, options = options)
4.
shinyAppDir(x)
3.
as.shiny.appobj.character(appDir)
2.
as.shiny.appobj(appDir)
1.
runApp("for_help")
```

**I am unable to identify what component needs to be wrapped in `header` and/or `footer` in the `tabsetPanel`. Please guide me what I'm missing.**

Comment: As you are not using `nav_panel()` or `nav_menu()`, perhaps you should comment out `library(bslib)`.

Comment: Try with `tabsetPanel(id = ns("tabs"))`, i.e. you have to name the `id=` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at the docs: `?tabsetPanel`. Under the **Usage** section we see:

```r
tabsetPanel(
  ...,
  id = NULL,
  selected = NULL,
  type = c("tabs", "pills", "hidden"),
  header = NULL,
  footer = NULL
)
```

The first parameter to `tabsetPanel()` is `...` and not `id`.

As such, when you pass the `id` by position as the first argument, it goes in as `...`. Since `...` expect `tabPanel()` elements, the error you see is thrown.

The solution is to pass `id` as a named argument to `tabsetPanel()`:

```r
tabsetPanel(id = ns("tabs"))
```